# Images wont save to project folder

Tags: php

I have an image upload index for a project. An link to the image is created and saved to a phpMyAdmin DB and the image is supposed to save to my /image folder in the project files. The index saves the link/directory access in the DB but the image itself is not saved. So essentially I have a link to an empty image in my image folder!

I had no issues with the code until I moved from a localhost to a blacknight server.

Any suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

I have tried using BLOB instead of TEXT for images in the database and that has not worked.

I have given permissions to access that for Read/Write in FileZilla.

I have corrected all the DB connections and file paths.

```
<?php

   // Create database connection

   $db = mysqli_connect("*HOST*", "*USERNAME*", "*PASSWORD*", "*DB_NAME*");

  // Initialize message variable
  $msg = "";

  // If upload button is clicked ...
  if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
  // Get image name
$image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
// Get text

$image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);
 $regplate = $_POST['regplate'];

// image file directory
$target = "/wwwroot/*DOMAIN_NAME*/images/".basename($image);

$sql = "INSERT INTO images (regplate, image, image_text) VALUES ('$regplate', '$image', '$image_text')";
// execute query
mysqli_query($db, $sql);

if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
    $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
   }else{
    $msg = "Failed to upload image";
    }
    }
   $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
  ?>
```

I expected that this line would submit the file into the /images folder

```
 // image file directory
$target = "/wwwroot/*DOMAIN_NAME*/images/".basename($image);
```

Comment: Is `wwwroot` really in the root directory for the entire server?  Can you show how you are navigating to that directory on your command prompt and then the output of `pwd`?

Comment: PD of [How to get useful error messages in PHP?](//stackoverflow.com/q/845021) / [move\_upload\_file, return false but still working and not moving correctlly](//stackoverflow.com/q/9368664) / var_dump($_FILES)

Answer (score -1):

No need of specifying full path to folder

```
<?php

       // Create database connection

       $db = mysqli_connect("*HOST*", "*USERNAME*", "*PASSWORD*", "*DB_NAME*");

      // Initialize message variable
      $msg = "";

      // If upload button is clicked ...
      if (isset($_POST['upload'])) {
      // Get image name
    $image = $_FILES['image']['name'];
    // Get text

    $image_text = mysqli_real_escape_string($db, $_POST['image_text']);
     $regplate = $_POST['regplate'];

    // image file directory
    $target = "./images/".basename($image);

    $sql = "INSERT INTO images (regplate, image, image_text) VALUES ('$regplate', '$image', '$image_text')";
    // execute query
    mysqli_query($db, $sql);

    if (move_uploaded_file($_FILES['image']['tmp_name'], $target)) {
        $msg = "Image uploaded successfully";
       }else{
        $msg = "Failed to upload image";
        }
        }
       $result = mysqli_query($db, "SELECT * FROM images");
      ?>
```